# Troubles with altair library in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, calculator, startup, altair

I'm running the following code: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-an-interactive-startup-growth-calculator-with-python-d224816f29d5. And I'm trying to make an startup growth calculator.

When I run the part of visualizaton I've the following issue:

```
# This is a variable forecast for modelling different growth-rates.
# Initial growth rate is set to be the current growth rate

# This cannot be 0, as growth rate wouldn't work
start_revenue = INITIAL_REVENUE if INITIAL_REVENUE > 100 else 100
scale = (-CURRENT_CASH_GBP, CURRENT_CASH_GBP * 2)

monthly_growth_percent = WEEKLY_GROWTH_PERCENT * 4

# Visualization

# Slider 
slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=100, step=0.1, name='Monthly growth rate (%)')

# Use selector to select the monthly growth with slider and choose the initial growth rate
selector = alt.selection_single(fields=['month_growth'], bind=slider, init={'month_growth': monthly_growth_percent})

# Create base chart to add on
base = alt.Chart(df[['date', 'cash_0g']]).transform_window(
    # Use count() to find out the current month we're on (i.e. the index), as we use that as the power for our growth rate
    index='count()'
).transform_calculate(
    # Transform a % growth rate (i.e. 7) into sometime useful (i.e. 1.07).
    # Raise that to our current month (i.e. for month 2, 1.07 ** 2 = ~1.145), and multiply that by our revenue amount (~1.145 * 500)
    forecast_revenue = ((1+(selector.month_growth / 100)) ** alt.datum.index) * start_revenue
).transform_window(
    # Take what is in practice the cumulative product of revenue (i.e. total revenue earned so far)
    forecast_total_revenue = 'sum(forecast_revenue)', frame=[None, 0]
).transform_calculate(
    # Add cumprod to current cash to find cash standing (i.e. if we have £100k cash, and 10 months of £10k revenue, we have £200k now)
    adj_cash = alt.datum.cash_0g + alt.datum.forecast_total_revenue
).encode(x='yearmonth(date):T')

# Define three variables on the chart with 3 different markers
cash = base.encode(y=alt.Y('adj_cash:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=scale))).mark_area(opacity=0.75)
revenue = base.encode(y='forecast_total_revenue:Q').mark_line(color='#f26522', size=5) 
revenue_growth = base.encode(y='forecast_revenue:Q').mark_line(color='purple', size=5)

# Combine these 3 markers into on chart
charts = cash + revenue + revenue_growth

# Add slider to the chart
chart_final = charts.add_selection(selector).interactive().properties(width=850)
chart_final
```

This is the following issue:

```
{
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "altair.vegalite.v5.schema.core.SelectionParameter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/ipykernel_14944/1252014563.py in <module>
     14 
     15 # Use selector to select the monthly growth with slider and choose the initial growth rate
---> 16 selector = alt.selection_single(fields=['month_growth'], bind=slider, init={'month_growth': monthly_growth_percent})
     17 
     18 # Create base chart to add on

~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\altair\\utils\\deprecation.py in new_obj(*args, **kwargs)
     64         def new_obj(*args, **kwargs):
     65             warnings.warn(message, AltairDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=1)
---> 66             return obj(*args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68         new_obj._deprecated = True

~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\altair\\vegalite\\v5\\api.py in selection_single(**kwargs)
    730 def selection_single(**kwargs):
    731     \"\"\"'selection_single' is deprecated.  Use 'selection_point'\"\"\"
--> 732     return _selection(type=\"point\", **kwargs)
    733 
    734 

~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\altair\\vegalite\\v5\\api.py in _selection(type, **kwds)
    457         raise ValueError(\"\"\"'type' must be 'point' or 'interval'\"\"\")
    458 
--> 459     return param(select=select, **param_kwds)
    460 
    461 

~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\altair\\vegalite\\v5\\api.py in param(name, value, bind, empty, expr, **kwds)
    426         parameter.param_type = \"selection\"
    427     else:
--> 428         parameter.param = core.SelectionParameter(
    429             name=parameter.name, bind=bind, value=value, expr=expr, **kwds
    430         )

TypeError: altair.vegalite.v5.schema.core.SelectionParameter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'"
}
```

The output is supposed to be an interactive graph

I'm trying to change the section of visualization but it doesn't works, this is the change that I've made:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# Define the data (assuming 'cash_0g' is a field in your data)
# Replace this with your actual data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01'],
    'cash_0g': [100000, 120000, 140000]
})

# Define the selection
selector = alt.selection_single(name='selector_name', fields=['month_growth'], bind=slider)

# Create the base chart
base = alt.Chart(data).transform_window(
    index='count()'
).transform_calculate(
    forecast_revenue='pow(1 + (selector_name.month_growth / 100), datum.index) * 100'
).transform_window(
    forecast_total_revenue='sum(forecast_revenue)',
    frame=[None, 0]
).transform_calculate(
    adj_cash='datum.cash_0g + datum.forecast_total_revenue'
).encode(x=alt.X('yearmonth(date):T'))

# Define the scale
scale = (-data['cash_0g'].max(), data['cash_0g'].max() * 2)

# Encode the variables on the chart
cash = base.encode(y=alt.Y('adj_cash:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=scale))).mark_area(opacity=0.75)
revenue = base.encode(y='forecast_total_revenue:Q').mark_line(color='#f26522', size=5)
revenue_growth = base.encode(y='forecast_revenue:Q').mark_line(color='purple', size=5)

# Combine the variables into one chart
charts = cash + revenue + revenue_growth

# Add the selector to the chart
chart_final = charts.add_selection(selector).properties(width=850)

# Show the chart
chart_final
```

It functs, but the chart isn't interactive

[image]

This is how the correct chart looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In altair 5 you need to use `value` instead of `init` as per https://altair-viz.github.io/releases/changes.html#grammar-changes. Try changing

```
init={'month_growth': monthly_growth_percent}
```

to

```
value=[{'month_growth': monthly_growth_percent}]
```